# Connecting an API to my mobile application. Error using SwiftUI "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report"

Tags: json, database, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to build an application that will show the stats from a game called Beyond All Reason by pulling the statistics from the replays feature from the game. I am fairly new to working with APIs so there may just be an error in my code that apple us having issues debugging?

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ProfileView: View {
    var user: User? // Change to optional user
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @State private var isDropDownOpen = false // State to track dropdown open/close
    @State private var replays: [Replay] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        if let user = user { // Check if user is not nil
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        Section {
                            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                                // Initials area
                                Text(user.initials)
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .frame(width: 72, height: 72)
                                    .background(Color(.systemGray3))
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                
                                // Content area
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                                    // Name area
                                    Text(user.fullname)
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        .padding(.top, 1)
                                    
                                    // Email Area
                                    Text(user.email)
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                                .padding(.leading, 8) // Add padding between the initials and the content
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Dropdown Menu
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            isDropDownOpen.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: isDropDownOpen ? "chevron.down.circle.fill" : "chevron.up.circle.fill")
                                .font(.title)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    
                    if isDropDownOpen {
                        // Content for the dropdown menu when it's open
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            
                            // Sign out function in dropdown
                            Section("Account") {
                                Button(action: {
                                    // Implement sign-out functionality && leave it empty for preview
                                    viewModel.signOut()
                                }) {
                                    Text("Sign Out")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            // Version area in dropdown
                            Section("General") {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Version")
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Text("1.0.0")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white) // Set text color to white
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white) // Set the foreground color to white for the text
                    }
                    
                    // List of replays
                    List(replays) { replay in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Replay ID: \(replay.id)")
                            Text("Start Time: \(replay.startTime)")
                            Text("Duration: \(replay.durationMs)")
                            Text("Map: \(replay.map.fileName), \(replay.map.scriptName)")
                            ForEach(replay.allyTeams) { allyTeam in
                                Text("Winning Team: \(allyTeam.winningTeam ? "Yes" : "No")")
                                ForEach(allyTeam.players) { player in
                                    Text("Player: \(player.name)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // Bottom Bar with adjusted spacing for icons and grey line separator
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        // Usage of CustomBarButton
                        CustomBarButton(systemName: "house", destination: AnyView(ContentView()))
                        CustomBarButton(systemName: "magnifyingglass", destination: AnyView(searchPage()))
                        CustomBarButton(systemName: "message", destination: AnyView(chatLog()))
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background(Color.black)
                }
                .background(Color.black)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
                .onAppear {
                    fetchReplayData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            Text("No user found") // Display a message if user is nil
        }
    }
    
    func fetchReplayData() {
        guard let apiURL = URL(string: "https://www.api.bar-rts.com/replays?page=1&limit=24&hasBots=false&endedNormally=true&players=osTas") else {
            print("Invalid API URL")
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: apiURL) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching replays: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data received")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601 // Adjust date decoding strategy if needed
                let replayResponse = try decoder.decode(ReplayResponse.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.replays = replayResponse.data
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // Preview with a sample user
        let user = User(id: "", fullname: "", email: "")
        return ProfileView(user: user)
    }
}

struct ReplayResponse: Codable {
    let totalResults: Int
    let page: Int
    let limit: Int
    let data: [Replay]
}

struct Replay: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let startTime: Date
    let durationMs: Int
    let map: MapInfo
    let allyTeams: [AllyTeam]
}

struct MapInfo: Codable {
    let fileName: String
    let scriptName: String
}

struct AllyTeam: Codable, Identifiable {
    let winningTeam: Bool
    let players: [Player]
    let AIs: [AI] // Assuming AI structure is similar to Player
    
    var id: String { UUID().uuidString }
}

struct Player: Codable {
    let name: String
}

struct AI: Codable {
    // AI properties if any
}
```

I have used postman to try and identify the data structure of the database. I'm not fully sure if i have this part correct...

I'm expecting for the stats to be displayed on to the profile view page and for it to update live from the api. Once its working I want to then try and formulate the results into the forms of graphs.

At the minute I am just getting the error "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report". I have tried uploading a bug report but apples developer feedback page seems to be having issues as it produces a blank page once logged in.

Comment: It is a typo, comment out sections until you find it

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I have just tried this to no avail. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That is the only way to find it, whatever `body` is showing that error. go line by line (starting "inside") and comment out individual views. At some point the message will go away and that is where the typo is. SwiftUI looses the ability to fully identify typos when `body` hits a certain complexity. Commenting out simplifies the `body`. As a general rule if your `.swift` file for a `View` is more than 50ish lines it is too long.

Comment: A really big red flag are those `AnyView`, Apple highly discourages its use but the `List` with the 2 nested `ForEach` is also a weak spot.

Comment: If the indentation is correct then that function is declared inside of `body` which is incorrect. Move it outside instead. Not an error but NavigationView is deprecated